# List all blogs apart from the current blog and main blog in WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, multisite

I need to list all current WordPress Multisite Blogs apart from the one the user is on and the main blog. We have a 404 page where we'd like to recommend other blogs (physical places) apart from the blog the user is current on and the main blog.

Here is our structure:

Main Blog (places)
Blog 1 (New York)
Blog 2 (London)
Blog 3 (Paris)

I can list all blogs but need to remove the main blog and the one the user is cirrently on from the list.

```
<?php

$bcount = get_blog_count();

global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE 
spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'"));
if(!empty($blogs)){
?><ul class="menu"><?php
foreach($blogs as $blog){
    $details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);
    if($details != false){
        $addr = $details->siteurl;
        $name = $details->blogname;
        if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1)&&($show_main != 1))){
            ?>
            <li class="menu-item<?php if($counter == get_current_blog_id()){ echo ' current-menu-item';}?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $addr; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?></ul><?php
} ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list all blogs except the current one and the main one:

```
$blogs = get_sites(
    array(
    'number' => 99999999,
    'site__not_in' => array( get_current_blog_id(), 1 )
    )
);

foreach( $blogs as $blog ) {
    $addr = $blog->siteurl;
    $name = $blog->blogname;
    echo $addr . " - " . $name . "<br>";
}
```